# Gitlab docker runner on Windows : msbuild fails

Tags: docker, msbuild, gitlab, nuget, gitlab-ci-runner

For months I’m using several shared runners to run my GitLab CI job. All my runners are running on linux host or macOS and it works great! This job is compiling .Net Standard project using mono:latest image.

I use msbuild with nugget restore and here is my problem. I recently added my first shared runner on **Windows**, still using docker runner as usual such as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#option-1-use-local-system-volume-mounts-to-start-the-runner-container) (which is the way I always do). But with this new **Windows** shared runner and only this one my job fails when msbuild restore nugget packages from our local (subnetwork) nugget repository.

I tried installing another docker runner on another Windows host and same issue. I got this error:

> error : Unable to load the service index for source
> http://skirnir/NuGet/index.json error :   No such host is known

Skirnir is a local server where my nugget packages are hosted.
I tried from my job to "curl http://login:pwd@skirnir/NuGet/index.json" and it works so when msbuild is executed from within the container using mono image it can access to Skirnir! But msbuild restore always fails to fetch packages.
I tried to replace skirnir with its IP but same problem because index.json reference skirnir in "@id": "http://skirnir/NuGet/".

Here is my gitlab job:

```yaml
cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
  paths:
    - packages

variables:
  MAIN_DIR: "Proj1"

before_script:
  - nuget help > /dev/null
  - cp $HOME/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config .
  - nuget sources add -Name skirnir_ci -Source http://skirnir/NuGet/index.json -UserName $NUGET_USER -Password $NUGET_PASSWORD -configfile $(pwd)/NuGet.Config
  - export NUGET_PACKAGES=$(pwd)/packages

build pcl:
  image: mono
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  retry: 2
  only:
    - tags
    - branches
    - web
  variables:
    PROJECT: "Proj1"
  script:
    - export MSBUILD_PROP="/p:Configuration=Release;RestoreConfigFile=$(pwd)/NuGet.Config"
    - msbuild /t:restore "$MSBUILD_PROP" $MAIN_DIR/$PROJECT/$PROJECT.csproj
    - msbuild "$MSBUILD_PROP" $MAIN_DIR/$PROJECT/$PROJECT.csproj
```

Any idea?

Comment: Probably `curl` and `msbuild` resolve differently. Easy and 'hacky' solution is to edit the `hosts` file in the container (add a new line) and explicitly tie the IP and the hostname, like: `10.10.10.10    skirnir` and see if that works as a start. Most likely your container is not fully aware of the `skirnir` hostname, so it's probably a resolving issue.